# How to text-align in textbox in right bottom corner?

Tags: javascript, html, css, textbox, text-align

I want to align a text inside a textbox at bottom right. I am able to align to right by using

```
text-align:right;
```

but this leaves with some space at bottom. I want to achieve what is shown in below image
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve it using the `padding` property. See the snippet below. You can try it and adjust the values in [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/o3sofqa3/)

```css
.my-input{
  padding: 6px 8px 0 8px;
  text-align: right;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" class="my-input">
```

Comment: what is the default padding of a textbox?

Comment: IDK, it may depends on the browser, but things such padding, margin, etc.. are better set manually than depending on the defaults.